# Getting familiar with Entity Framework when using existing database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We are currently rewriting an existing internal ASP.NET Web Forms application. Our application consists of a Web Api back end which uses Entity Framework 6 for data access and an front end which uses AngularJS.

We have an existing large database that I've created EF models using the Code-First Using Existing Database method and we are using data transfer object classes as inputs/outputs to our API methods so we aren't directly exposing our model classes. So basically, I'm trying to become proficient with EF, Web Api and AngularJS all at the same time.  For the most part I'm fairly comfortable with the latter two, but for EF I haven't completely gotten comfortable with.  I've watched a lot of the videos on Microsoft Virtual Academy but this is the first time I've had some hands-on experience with it.

We've been working on this application for a few months and so far we've only had to work with CRUD operations on our entities (POCO DTO's) which are flat objects with simple properties.  However, we've finally come across some situations where we need to deal not only with our classes, but properties which are classes themselves; a parent-child relationship.

Therefore, I have the following questions:

1. I see that when we have a proper foreign key relationship in our DB, that virtual properties are created in EF, which from what I recall are to support lazy-loading.  However, lazy-loading isn't really feasible in this environment where we are using web services (Web Api).  Our object model does allow for some really large hierarchy of classes where a fully populated object and its children would mean a large amount of data would be passed around when that really isn't necessary, so in most cases a first level object is all we need.  In some cases however, we do want to populate child classes, so my question is how do we do that, and where do we do that?  I've looked at the automatically-generated code in the DB Context but we have also used scaffolded code to create our controllers.  Which place do we need to do this?  I've seen code samples showing how do to this but it hasn't said specifically where this code lies.  It appears to be within a controller but I could be wrong.
2. If we do allow for 2- or more level hierarchy of objects, does EF automatically handle operations (updates, deletes, etc.) -- for example, if we have a "Company" object which has a collection of "Customer" objects, and we delete the "Company" object, do the related "Customer" objects get deleted too?  Also, is a multi-step operation like that automatically performed within a transaction or do we need to explicitly set that up?
3. If I modify a model class or the DB context, seeing as this code is automatically-generated, that's generally bad practice as my changes could be overwritten, so I am assuming the controller code is where I want to make my changes.  I am aware of database migrations but I have no experience with them and I am sure I'll need to use them at some point because I am fairly confident that our database may not have all the foreign key relationships necessary for EF to do everything we need at the moment.

I know this is a long post, but if anyone can give some guidance on how to do some of these things because it's not only me that's having to deal with this but I have two other developers on my team who are working on this project and we are all as inexperienced with this as the others are. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. For the purpose of sending data across a web service, I'd suggest creating a DTO to hold the data you want to send and mapping your entities to the DTO instead of trying to send the entities themselves in your payload. It also protects your API from changes to your entity.
2. Cascading deletes are configurable, iirc, but I'm not 100% sure what the default is. Transactions are generally not implicit, so you will want to use those where you require them.
3. Not exactly sure what you are asking here. In general, how your entities/tables change depends on if you are using database-first or code-first. If you are using database-first (you will have a .edmx file in your solution that has the model matching your schema), you just update the SQL directly and update your entity model via the .edmx. If you use code-first, you will change the entities how you want them and run a database migration to update your database to match.

MSDN article about code-first migration: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: We're already doing #1.  This also gives us the flexibility to transform the data if we want, however right now it's essentially a clone of the model classes (with more appropriate property names).  As for #3, there is no edmx file.  I created the model classes by adding a new ADO Data Model and selecting Code First from Database.  I can't recall exactly why we chose not to use EF Model from Database (I think our boss recommended Code First from Database).